# Delete first 20 row that were created in DB

Tags: android, mysql

I have created a recently viewed items table. In that I would like to delete the first 20 items how do I go about deleting them?

First in the sense here the first 20 items that was created.

I know the query:

DELETE FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20, 18446744073709551615; (this is random number)

How do I write this in Android format by using DB.Dlete

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //DELETE FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20, 18446744073709551615;
        db.delete(TABLE_RECENT_VIEWED, "ORDER BY " +  KEY_RECENTVIEWED_ID_LOCAL + " DESC LIMIT 10, 18446744073709551615", null);
db.close();
```

I keep getting E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "ORDER": syntax error

Can somebody guide me delete only first 20 records? (for example i have 40 records of which 1 is first record and 40 is the last record.)

Not sure where I am going wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this sql syntax works `        //DELETE FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 20, 18446744073709551615;
`

Answer (score 0):

What you want: delete the **FIRST 20 ROWS**

First you will have to get that rows by:

```
SELECT Id
    FROM table
    ORDER By Id ASC
    LIMIT 20
```

You should be using ascending (`ASC`) in the order by, if you really want the first 20 rows. If you use descending (`DESC`), that would be the last 20 rows.

After that, you can now delete the records by:

```
DELETE FROM table
    WHERE Id IN (
        SELECT Id
            FROM table
            ORDER By Id ASC
            LIMIT 10
    )
```

Comment: You can do it in one SQL statement, as the OP has already showed, and that I s not what the question is about.

Comment: I have tried the above code. I didn't do anything.. I think it would be easier to write a code using db.delete().. I am not able to do it. Syntax for this would be good. Thanks!